# ASP.NET MVC - how to capture and save multiple complex ListBox values to database

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

So, I've created a View that contains two ListBoxes, **AvailableServices** and **SelectedServices**:

```
                @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.AvailableServices, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { id = "serviceID" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AvailableServices)

                @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedServices, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { id = "selectedserviceID" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedServices)
```

For reference, here is my ViewModel:

```
namespace Services.ViewModels
{
public class SPServiceTypeViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SPCompanyAccountID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Service Category")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ServiceCategory { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Available Services")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableServices { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Your Services")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectedServices { get; set; }
}
}
```

My Controller populates the **AvailableServices** ListBox without issue. And I wrote some JavaScript that lets the user move items (including **id** and **label**) from the **AvailableServices** ListBox to the **SelectedServices** listbox. No problem there either.

Now here's my problem... I've read a variety of posts but I still don't understand how to best pass data from my **SelectedServices** ListBox back to my controller upon form submission, because I need to capture both the **id** and **label** for each selection.

My goal here is to create a new database row in my **SPServiceType** table for each item in the **SelectedServices** ListBox, and I'm clueless. Right now my Controller for saving data looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(SPServiceTypeViewModel viewModel)
    {
    foreach (var item in viewModel.SelectedServices)
           {
               var spServiceType = new SPServiceType
               {
                   SPCompanyAccountId = viewModel.SPCompanyAccountID,
                   ServiceCategory = ???,
               };
               db.SPServiceType.Add(spServiceType);
               db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Create", "SPServiceLocation");
    }
```

Do I need to not use IENumerable in my ViewModel? Do I need to use JavaScript to pass my **SelectedServices** values to a hidden List<> prior to submission so that my model binding is easier to accomplish?

To reiterate, I want to capture the **id** and **label** values of the selections.

Any code examples on how to approach this within the View, or Post action in the Controller, or general approach advice, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928135/mvc3-viewmodels-and-controller-functionalty-suggested-design-patterns).

The recommendation at the time was to accept the selected values in the POST and use a repository pattern (caching if necessary) to translate the values to labels as needed.